# Why is irb returning NameError: uninitialized constant for all objects in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, uninitialized-constant

I am half way through building a Q&A app and I have successfully seeded my database and can see that objects have been created both in my browser and in the server logs and previously in irb.  Now when I went to try to inspect an object in irb, for every object I give it, irb returns "NameError: uninitialized constant".  For example:

```
2.0.0-p481 :001 > user = User.find(1)
NameError: uninitialized constant User
    from (irb):1
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
2.0.0-p481 :002 > question = Question.find(1)
NameError: uninitialized constant Question
    from (irb):2
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
2.0.0-p481 :003 > user = User.find
NameError: uninitialized constant User
    from (irb):3
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
2.0.0-p481 :004 > user = User.new
NameError: uninitialized constant User
    from (irb):4
    from /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I'm new to programming, so if anyone could explain why this might be happening it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're running `irb` when you want `rails console` (or `rails c` for short).

Comment: Oh my!  I can't believe I mixed them up! Thanks @Eliot!

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to use rails console, not irb.

> rails console

(I assume you are building a Rails application)